# Make a form button alter the current page's display

Tags: html, sql, jsp

Forgive me, I've never used jsp before, and have limited knowledge of html also.

What I want is for a form button which will take input from a form and use that in an SQL query, and have a table with the results of the query appear once the button is pressed.

I have some example code that I've used, but I can't quite figure out how to make the button's action create a table on the current page.

within my body I have:

```
<form action="demo.jsp" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Which country?</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='country' value="${country}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='action2' value='Search'>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and then outside I have:

```
<c:if test="${param.action == 'Search'}">
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>

        <sql:query var="QryCountry">
            Select *
            from db.TEAM
            where country = ?
                <sql:param value="${country}" />
        </sql:query>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${QryCountry.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.team_year}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.country}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.position}" /></td>
                </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:set var="country" value="" />
    </table>
</c:if>
```

but pressing the button doesn't appear to be doing anything. Any suggestions? I'd be happy to clarify anything if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me If I'm wrong. Look at `<c:if/>` expression in your code-snippet, it should be,

```
<c:if test="${param.action2 == 'Search'}">
```